# Android installation - sdk manager.exe does not work

Tags: android

I installed the android SDK from developer.android.com for Windows (installer_r08-windows.exe).  I installed to the default location, C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows.  When I try to run SDK Manager.exe, a console window briefly pops up, but disappears.. nothing else happens.  If I try to run this from the command line, nothing happens, either (and no output).

I have JDK 1.6.0_20 installed, and JAVA_HOME environment variable points to this folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20)

Help?

Comment: hi, I have the same problem, did you have the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me (copied from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work-android))

> Step #1: Open up a command prompt.
>
> Step #2: Use the cd command to move to wherever you installed your
>   Android SDK.
>
> Step #3: Run tools\android.
>
> If that does not work, you should have information dumped to the
>   command prompt that will help you diagnose your setup problem.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem.
I had installed Java SDK 1.4 (which is not compatible) so I installed 1.6 and add dir to PATH variable and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already installed Java SE Development Toolkit 1.6? If so, perhaps you already had an older JDK installed and when you try to run "SDK Manager.exe" it first fetchs the older one. There are two possible solutions:

Rollback your JDK instalations, and when you have no JDK present in your netbook, then install the 1.6 version.

OR

Go to "Control Panel"-> System -> Advanced -> "Environment Variables"

In system variables look for "Path" variable and click Edit. Check if the value field doesn't have the path to your Java JDK’s bin folder. If that already exists substitute to the correct one. (ie "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin"). Otherwise, you need to insert this path at the front of the list. Insert the path followed by a ';'. Click ok all the way and reboot your machine.

After this, give another chance to "SDK Manager.exe"! :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can be happen due to the difference in 32-bit/64-bit versions. If you have downloaded the Android SDK for 32-bit version and if you have the 64-bit system, then this kind of issue can happen. Please verify that you have the correct version downloaded and installed.