# How to run "android.bat sdk" in Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, sdk

I have downloaded and installed Android SDK and tried to start `android.bat sdk` but got following exception:

```
C:\products\Android\tools>android.bat sdk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path,
        java.library.path or the jar file
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:328)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
```

I have searched for solution a long time but I cannot get it to work.  Is there anything I have to set up first?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case this is still bothering anyone: I had this same problem. What I ended up doing was:

1. Searching for the swt.jar file (in your Android SDK directory, look at tools\lib\x86 or tools\lib\x86_64).
2. Unpack it using jar:

   `mkdir tmp`

   `cd tmp`

   `jar xf <path>\tools\lib\x86\swt.jar`
3. Copy the dlls to the `tools` folder.

   `copy tmp\*.dll <path>\tools`

After that I was able to run the SDK manager.

Comment: Thanks man.. You save my life am trying so many option from google but finally your solution works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:
Add the following in your android.bat file:

```
 -Dswt.library.path = {swt.jar folder path}
```

before this phrase:

```
com.android.manager.Main
```

Run android.bat

Answer (score 0):

I think the jar file is not placed in correct place.

SWT consists of two "parts" - the platform independent java-only part
and a platform dependent fragment. Did you add the platform dependent
fragment too?
So you need

```
org.eclipse.swt_VERSION.jar

org.eclipse.swt_WINDOWSYSTEM_PLATFORM_VERSION.jar
```

Refer this link for Setting the class [path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

[SWT Programming with Eclipse.](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3330861/SWT-Programming-with-Eclipse.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message displayed in the eclipse console when I was trying to load the sdk manager from within eclipse. All you need to do to fix it is run eclipse as administrator and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to swt.jar.

1. edit  "[your sdk_path]\tools\android.bat" file.
2. find words  "%Swt_path%\swt.jar"
3. Find your Eclipse plugin folder path.
4. be replace path by [your eclipse\plugins\swt.jar]

example

- before `classpath "% jar_path%;% swt_path%\swt.jar"`
- after `classpath "% jar_path%; C:\eclipse\plugins\ org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.102.1.v20130827-2048.jar"`

I hope this will help resolve the way.

Answer (score 0):

This questions its rather old, but I ran with the same issue as today, in 2015.
Also I expected the answers may not work, but oriented me to get this running without the need of running as Administrator, specially "Mehdi golnari" answer.

Based on Mehdi answer, we need add the same parameter that he added, but updated to work on the new SDK Tools (or android SDK). Mine is revision 24.3.3, SDK , so the `com.android.manager.Main` will not longer work for me, but insted we need it to be `com.android.sdkmanager.Main`.
Also we can use the variable that was set in the same bat before: `%swt_path%`.

So, add the following, almost at the end of the `android.bat` file:

```
"-Dswt.library.path=%swt_path%"
```

The resulting call code, should be a **single line** like this:

```
call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" "-Dswt.library.path=%swt_path%" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

This should help to run the `android.bat`, `SDK Manager.exe`, and `AVD Manager.exe`  without run as Administrator needs.