# I can't get my SDK manager to run. Can someone please give a solution please?

Tags: android, batch-file, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I get this text in the cmd when I open android.bat in sdk/tools/android.bat

I am using **android studio**. But i had eclipse- helios a while back, but I am not able to run the sdk manager via both or the exe file of the sdk itself.
I have tried to change the paths of the java environment a lot of times and I even tried to edit the android.bat file, but nothing worked.

what happens in the android studio is that, a progress bar shows up showing  the sdk manager is loading, but nothing happens after that.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

( p.s. why is the error still linked with eclipse when I've installed the **android studio** and everything again? )

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792446/how-to-run-android-bat-sdk-in-window-7

Comment: i've already tried the solutions provided there, they didn't work. Plus, i'm confused as to why the sdk is showing an error linked with eclipse even though i've installed everything new with the android studio bundle. I'm really confused.