# Android SDK does not open

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed both the latest ADT Bundle and the latest JAVA SE, and have configured the PATH variable with the java/bin location in the first place. However, still the SDK Manager won't run. When I try to open the manager from Eclipse, a window pops up saying "Initializing" and then it closes and nothing happens. When I run the android.bat file from the SDK, I get the following error:

[image]

Any help to run the SDK Manager would be highly appreciated. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. ADT version is v22.3.0-887826 and JAVA SE version is 7 update 45.

**Fixed the issue**

Apparently, I have to run the SDK Manager as an administrator. This fixed the issue. The "access denied" part should have given me some hint! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work-android)

Comment: OK I saw that and uninstalled my antivirus and disable the firewall. However, I STILL get the error! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed the issue**

Apparently, I have to run the SDK Manager as an administrator. This fixed the issue. The "access denied" part should have given me some hint! Thanks everyone!

**Another permanent fix to the issue**

Taken from: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/zbazK_MeKRs/gtBUnVNI1hAJ

> Hello, I did the following
>
> - Open the windows explorer
> - Paste this address
>   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\
> - Right click on folder Temp, then
>   Properties, then Security, then Advanced Then click on button Change
>   permissions
> - Remove all permissions
> - Select: Include inheritable
>   permissions from this object's parent
> - Select: Replace all child object
>   permissions with inheritable permissions from this object
> - Click OK....
>
> Maybe a windows' update changed permissions. I hope this works with you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you try to install java JDK and after then you try to install Android ADT Bundle

Comment: Yes I did install the JDK before. But I don't understand how this would create/solve the issue, as the ADT bundle just comes as a zip file with nothing to install.

Comment: Yes I did, or else how would I run the android.bat file.

Comment: k fine,install SDK Manger with updated version 19 and install the Adt plugin eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

I have already read about problems due to space in instal path.

In your case: D:\Android SDK\..."

Comment: I have over 40 GB of free space on all my drives.

Comment: No excuse me for my english, space was in your case those one into: "D:\Android SDK\..."