# How do I set ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, sdk, adt

I'm working with Eclipse on Windows 7, x64. I'm getting an error when running ADT bundle of android development:

> Error: Error parsing the AVDs
> Unable to get the Android SDK home directory.
> Make sure the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set up.

I know what the issue is. Is it because it is linked to a wrong directory C:users:????

How do I set this environment variable android_sdk_home to the proper directory?

Comment: Kindly go to this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: wait for a while i'll give you all the stpes

Comment: @OlegArsyonov - I was not aware Android used `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. I know it *does* use `ANDROID_HOME`, `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`, and the last two should be set because the tools internally use them. Where did you latch onto `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`? Here's the reference on `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`: [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ). The fellow named Digit works on the NDK team.

Comment: Also see [SDK Manager.exe doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27664180/608639)

Answer (score 140):

#### `ANDROID_HOME`

Installation directory of **Android SDK** package.

*Example: `C:\AndroidSDK` or `/usr/local/android-sdk/`*

#### `ANDROID_USER_HOME`

Location of SDK related **data/user** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\` or `~/.android/`*

#### `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

**Deprecated** (in Android Studio), use `ANDROID_HOME` instead.

#### `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`

Installation directory of **Android NDK** package. (WITHOUT ANY SPACE)

*Example: `C:\AndroidNDK` or `/usr/local/android-ndk/`*

#### `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`

**Deprecated** (in Android Studio 4.2), use `ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT` instead.

#### `ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT`

**Deprecated** (in Android Studio), use path to subdirectory `.android` via `ANDROID_USER_HOME` instead.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\` or `~/`*

#### `ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME`

Location of **emulator-specific** **data** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\` or `~/.android/`*

#### `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`

Location of **AVD-specific** **data** files.

*Example: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\avd\` or `~/.android/avd/`*

#### `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`

Installation directory of **JDK** (aka Java SDK) package.

**Note:** This is used to run Android Studio(and other Java-based applications). Actually when you run Android Studio, it checks for `JDK_HOME` then `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to use.

Comment: I had a difficult time getting Android Studio respecting these environment variables. I would set the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` but Android Studio would still want to create AVDs in the `~/.android/avd` directory. Any idea what could be the issue? I ended up using a symlink from `~/.android` to my desired directory.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I had same issue, somehow Android Studio is not honoring any of these environment variables, at last symlink worked well.

Comment: Created a symbolic link using `ln -s $ANDROID_SDK_HOME ~/.android`

Comment: Worked for me! Also great to read up here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#android_sdk_root

Comment: On windows look in AppData\Local\Android\

Answer (score 28):

If you face the same error, here are the step by step instructions:

1. Open control panel
2. Then go to System
3. Then go to Change Environment Variables of the User
4. Then click create a new environment variables
5. Create a new variable named ANDROID_SDK_HOME
6. Set its value to your Android directory, like `C:/users/<username>/.android`

Comment: If this is the answer, then you should accept your own answer. That's how Stack Overflow works. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448).

Comment: This does not look quite right: `C:/users/<username>/.android`. That looks like the `ANDROID_HOME` directory, and not the SDK directory. The SDK directory would be `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. Here's the reference on `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`: [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ). The fellow named Digit works on the NDK team.

Comment: @jww - did you read the thread you linked? It never even references `ANDROID_HOME`. It only refers to 3 variables as 'standard.' In addition, it specifies `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` as equaling `~/.android/` on Linux, which corresponds to `%USERPROFILE%\.android` on Windows.

The fact is that, you don't need to specify the `.android` subfolder. On Windows, you just set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to whatever folder it resides in. So, in the OP's case, it would be set to `C:\Users\<username>` or `%UserProfile%` and for others, wherever you like.

The only caveat is that the (parent) folder must exist.

Comment: @Frank - yes, I read it (it was my question to the NDK folks). `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is the one variable I am aware of that Android uses to determine the SDK location. Who knows what `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` is. Eclipse [does not document it](http://www.google.com/search?q="ANDROID_SDK_HOME"+site:eclipse.org), and its not obvious to me why yet another variable is needed. My best guess is you should set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`  to `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

Answer (score 20):

Copy your SDK path and assign it to the environment variable **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**

Refer pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

1. Open control panel
2. click System
3. Then go to Change Environment Variables
4. Then click create a new environment variables
5. Create a new variable named ANDROID_HOME
   path C:\Android\sdk

Comment: @Kartiikeya, No, anywhere. But given path shouldnt contain `space`.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME will work if the path is correct.  If the path is incorrect or is unable to find ANDROID_HOME it will look for ANDROID_SDK_HOME.  That is why it works if you have either set correctly.

Answer (score 8):

open your adt and open preferences, then modify directory with your sdk dir, it may help you
follow the pic link indication

[image]

Comment: I need ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable to set. SDK dir is nice and set..... How do I SET ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable? What that variable is? Where is it?

Comment: Please upload images through this site's interface (they get hosted on imgur).

Answer (score 6):

Just set the path to the Android SDK directory

**flutter config --android-sdk c:\android\sdk**

Answer (score 5):

Android SDK

Installing the Android SDK is also necessary. The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug apps for Android.

Cordova requires the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to be set. This should point to the `[ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk` directory (for example c:\android\android-sdk).

Next, update your PATH to include the tools/ and platform-tools/ folder in that folder. So, using `ANDROID_HOME`, you would add both `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`.

Reference : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 5):

Although the above answers mostly get them right, there is one slight issue with them all..
Follow these steps and you are good to go

1. Right click on This PC -> Properties
2. On the left pane select "Advanced System Settings"
3. On the new window select -> Advanced tab
4. Click on the "Environment Variables" button
5. On the first top section click on the "New" button

> set variable name -> ANDROID_HOME
>
> set variable value -> the custom location of the Android SDK

6. Now click on the newly created variable name and in the box below select "Path" and click on the Edit button
7. Now click on New and paste the location of the "platform-tools"
8. Again click on New and paste the location of the "tools"
   You can find the locations of the above platform-tools and tools - they are generally inside the Android SDK folder
9. MOST IMPORTANT OF ALL...

   > save all those by clicking ok 
   >   If you are using the terminal(cmd) close it and open it again

Answer (score 4):

from command prompt:

> set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\[wherever your sdk folder is]

should do the trick.

Comment: Whether  the  location  should  be  in  C  drive ?

Comment: READ before commenting for the love of Martha.   Several comments above tell you how to find the location of your particular SDK location.      set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\[wherever your sdk folder is] and that is explained above, look just above at the large image.

Answer (score 4):

AVD cant find SDK root, possibly because they are in different directories.Set your environment variables as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

****Just Simple Steps****

Follow this steps:

> 1.Right-click on 'My Computer'/'This PC' and select Properties. Go to Advanced system settings and select ‘Environmental Variables’ option

[Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAtjs.png)

> 2.Under the User Variable table, click New to open New User Variable dialog
>
> 3.Put ANDROID_HOME as Variable name and provide the path of the SDK folder next to Variable value.

[opened dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx8mQ.png)

> 4.Close the entire opened dialog box.

Follow this link for complete example

https://sndevelops.blogspot.com/2021/05/set-androidhome-and-path-variables.html

Comment: Snehal wadbudhe, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Another way to open the Advanced Properties is by using the Win+R keyboard shortcut and typing the command "sysdm.cpl ,3".

Comment: But I guess you should use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead of ANDROID_HOME, see below answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all Android Licenses were not accepted

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

accept all licences and then try:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Answer (score 0):

If Your flutter in vscode (Mac Os) Not Want to Trouble Anything !..

1. Open Extensions
2. Search For "Android Emulator"
3. Install "Android Emulator Launcher"

**If you already installed then Uninstall it and Newly install it there** !!

It Worked For me...