# ADB not responding in android studio

Tags: android

The dialog has 3 options: Wait more, Restart and Cancel. But all of them gives me the same result, i.e. a message Waiting for ADB appears and I can't do anything with Android Studio.

I have to kill the program using windows task manager! I'm using windows 7.

I tried some steps like rebuild project and clean project but it didn't work correctly....I also try kill the adb.exe in Task manager ..but it not show in the Task manager sometimes.

Can anyone help me on this?

the main problem is adb.exe not found in Task manager..

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and type in the below command

```
adb kill-server
```

then start server using the below command

```
adb start-server
```

This could remove any potential "waiting for adb" message if your adb server is not started correctly

**Note:** you may want to have adb in path variable

Comment: i typed in command prompt but it shows like "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Naveenbhat As I have put in the note.. you have to place adb in path variable - do the below: ... <Path to SDK Folder>\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable this link talks about setting someother variable.. you have to do for the path I have mentioned in the above variable.. the variable name is "PATH"