# Getting error in installing volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

In android studio I run this command git [clone](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)  on windows7 but after that android update project -p . command is not get runs in command prompt.I used this command in this way c:\volley>android update project -p . It shows 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: look like you didnt set system environment variables.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable

Comment: can you tell me how to install system variable

Comment: added link in above comment

Comment: http://tips.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-how-to-download-and-make-volley-jar/ please follow this may this help for you