# ANDROID_SDK_HOME

Tags: android-virtual-device

I've changed the AVD location from C to F folder cause lack space in C.Now AVD is not opening but giving this below message.Please advise why?

**Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set ANDROID\_SDK\_HOME environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Enviroment Variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, but seemingly points to a wrong directory. You will have to update ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the new directory.

Setting the variable is described on similar questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23043099/1666181

Comment: emulator failing to start cause  cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.