# How to Fix Build Failed on React-Native run-android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

So I'm getting this error

```
~/projects/personal-projects/react/myapp ⌚ 18:12:24
$ react-native run-android --variant=release  
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/user/projects/personal-projects/react/myapp/node_modules (22ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installRelease)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.706 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I already have my android sdk installed and I also have java installed.

this is what is in my `.bach_profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=$Home/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I've tried adding a local.properties file and added sdk.dir pointing to my Android/sdk folder. But still this error persists. How do I fix this?

Comment: Add environment variable in ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME pointing to jdk and android sdk

Comment: Where do I locate the jdk @ParasWatts

Comment: Search in /usr/lib/jvm/

Comment: I've added Java_home but it's still giving me the error @ParasWatts

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java check this thread for setting java_home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make file `local.properties` in folder `android` then add the following line on file

```
sdk.dir=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk(Please add your sdk path here)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME variables in environmental variables and 
tools and platform-tools in path of system to run android apk.

Setting [ANDROID_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36834833/3338287) variable in environmental variables.

Setting [JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/3338287) variable in environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to my problem was:

1) add my ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME paths in my .bash_profile

- Solution by @rana_sadam

2) Create `local.properties` and add `sdk.dir=<PATH TO ANDROID SDK>` inside the android folder.

- Solution by @nisarg Thakkar