# flutter installation error on window unable to determine the java version

Tags: android, flutter

How do I fix the flutter installation error?
this is the error I got:

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Koxbit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\bin\java
    X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\bin\java to determine the version

Answer (score 0):

for developing an android app and installing android SDK in windows you need to create some environment variables. the most important of these variables are ANDROID_SDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976475/9689717) to understand how to set these variables in windows.

after adding these changes check flutter doctor command.

Answer (score 0):

My windows JAVA_HOME path is set to: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath. I solved this problem by adding a bin directory under the following directory (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath) and copied the ,exe files in there.