# Windows 10: Android Studio Start Failed: Internal error. No reported fixes work

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've been struggling with trying to start Android Studio under 64-bit Windows 10 Pro. The installer file is named android-studio-ide-193.6626763-windows, so I assume the the version is 193.6626763.
I've searched very extensively and found quite a few reports of general "Android Studio Start Failed", and I've tried all of the suggested fixes for each of them. The most common of these is to reboot multiple times (I've tried 10 times with no luck), carefully examined and verified all environment variables (all are correct). Of course, I also tried several times uninstalling Android Studio and Java and its JDK & JRE, and even the JetBrains stuff using Revo Uninstaller 4 Pro. Then I scoured and cleaned the registry of any remaining traces left over (quite a few of them), then scoured every drive and folder for any file system traces and deleted all of them.

Then I rebooted a couple of times. Then I re-installed Java / JDK / JRE / JetBrains intellij and finally Android Studio. When I got exactly the same errors, I rebooted a couple of times and tried again.

Nothing helped.

Here is the full text of the error window:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1643)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:398)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:58)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.kt:247)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.kt:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$loadComponents$3(ApplicationImpl.java:346)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:346)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$6$loadComponentInEdtFuture$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
    ... 15 more Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 50: C:\Users\mjb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;\analytics.settings
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.getSettingsFile$analytics_shared(AnalyticsSettings.kt:336)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.loadSettingsData(AnalyticsSettings.kt:199)
    at com.android.tools.analytics.AnalyticsSettings.initialize(AnalyticsSettings.kt:283)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.initializeAndroidStudioUsageTrackerAndPublisher(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.setupAnalytics(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.run(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.kt:505)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    ... 28 more

----- JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

By the way, I don't have the authority to report this issue to Google, so please don't bother to suggest that.

May I please ask for some assistance?  Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: Hmmm... I think you're on to something there. Here are the four values:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ANDROID_SDK_HOME` must point to a single directory. On Windows the valid value would look like `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\` where `<USERNAME>` should be replaced with your account name.

You can also completely remove this environment variable so that the default location is used.

The issue can be caused by incorrect value of this variable: several directories separated with semicolons (`C:\Users\mjb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;`). It's not like `PATH` and cannot point to multiple directories.

Note that you need to logout/login or reboot after changing the environment variables.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976475/104891).

Comment: Bingo! That was it, exactly. Thank you enormously!!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I have 3 paths previously:

- `1. ANDROID_HOME`
- `2. ANDROID_SDK_HOME`
- `3. ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

pointed to the same path.

After I delete `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and only save the `ANDROID_HOME`  in environmental variables, it works.

PS: the path for `ANDROID_HOME` looks like  `D:\Android\Sdk`  in windows. (the default path of this should be in the `C` disk, so you need to **change it to the path of your sdk** and you can see your sdk location by opening android sdk in android studio and check the location.

I'm not 100% this works, but it works for me.

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the marketplace plugin installed? If yes, try removing it from %USERPROFILE%.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins\marketplace. Studio should restart and you can then install a compatible version from within the IDE.

this was work for me

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the following:

Go to C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Google

and delete AndroidStudio4.1. Then it should open as usually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried disabling my antivirus and it worked perfectly for me.
In my case I have to disable antivirus protection each time the Android studio starts, hope it works for you as well