# sdkmanager Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file

Tags: android, command-line-interface

I'm planning to develop Cordova app, so i was finishing my development environment. I successfully installed android-sdk and evrything finally i need install platform tools and build tools for start developing my app.
I'm doing everything in my CLI.
I tried to install build-tools like this :

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;29.0.3"
```

I'm getting the error like :

```
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
```

When i researched for 2 hours and everyone saying the permission of android-sdk directory. When i run this command :

```
ls -l mkdir /usr/lib/
```

I can see my android-sdk directory permission is :

```
drwxrwxrwx  12 root root   4096 أكت 21 17:03 android-sdk
```

My configurationn (~/.bashrc)

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/lib/android-sdk"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

I'm using Ubuntu OS 20.04 version. I tried to install platform-tools with the command sdkmanager but that's got worked success but i'm unable to install build-tools.
Anybody have any idea to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to set an environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` that points to a location in the user's home directory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable).

Comment: yes. i already updated it in my ~/.bashrc file. i updated question with that file. i can see when i run sdkmanager --version it outputs my version 4.0.1

Comment: Try `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/android-sdk"` instead of what you have now.

Comment: Yes i moved to $HOME and also tried but still sam problem.

Answer (score 8):

According this

> `drwxrwxrwx  12 root root   4096 أكت 21 17:03 android-sdk`

your Android SDK was installed under the root user, so you have to install platform tools like

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64"
```