# Path is being cleared when I close the command prompt

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, path

I am trying to get ionic to build to my android phone locally. I have been following the instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html. And I have gotten to the point where you type java or android into the terminal. I am getting the expected output from both after adding all of my variables to the path. However when I close the command promt and open it back up, if I type java it still works, but typing android causes it to say it can't be found

```
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

If I run

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

If I type android I get the desired output again. Then if I close and open the command prompt and type in android again I get the

```
'android' is not recognized...
```

error again. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

UPDATE:
I have gotten to a new error, turns out the previous error was occuring because OpenJDK gets installed with android studio, and it doesn't have the correct stuff for ionic (afaik). So I had to uninstall it then JAVA_HOME was pointing to the right thing.

But now I am running into a weird error where javac -version can't be found by ionic but I can run it as the next command without any problems:
[image: javac -version error]

Comment: You have to add android SDK path form Variable Window. using this command only set it temporary.

Comment: Check These Q&A's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable

Comment: I tried using the variable window and it doesn't work there either :(. It is like cmd is using a different context for the path. And that QA didn't seem to work for me, thanks for the link though.

Comment: Check this link for set path `https://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/`

Comment: None of those suggestions worked, but I found a fix for that problem. Now I have run into something new though :(