# npm run android generating an exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have node 15 installed on my ubuntu OS this is my first day with react I follw the documentation Installation Guide
https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

and this error occurred please help me out

```
npm -g create-react-native-app
```

then

```
create-react-app
```

When I run the app using the `npm run android`, I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file '/home/abubakar/Desktop/React/React Native proj/myApp/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle' line: 89
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
>   SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/abubakar/Desktop/React/React Native proj/myApp/android/local.properties'.
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ android: `react-native run-android`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ android script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/abubakar/.npm/_logs/2021-04-07T00_51_03_506Z-debug.log

Comment: Please follow this answer and set up ANDROID_SDK_ROOT https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976475

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Android Studio Home path is missing from your project.

For this go to your_project_directory/android

create a file local.properties

write the following code in it.

sdk.dir=path to your ANDROID_SDK_HOME in my case /root/Android/Sdk

you can get this path by opening the android studio and go to the SDK Manager.
[ANDROID_SDK_HOME_ATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Z9B.png)

It will work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You got Exception i.e SDK location not found means your Android_Home path is missing.
Your are using Ubuntu so just go to the Home which is present near Documents, Download section. After entered in Home just press ctrl+h, you will see lots of files then search .profile file and add following lines at last.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: add this for legacy
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME