# Flutter Project and run Android emulator in VS code getting environment variables error

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to Flutter and trying to set up an environment for my very first Flutter project.

I have installed the necessary apps & SDKs
[image]

Also, I have set the environment variables
[image]

I'm trying to 'Create Android Emulator' and getting this error
[image]

I'm trying to 'Run Android Emulator' and getting this error
[image]

```
You haven't configured your environment variables ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_HOME correctly in your system. Please refer this to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable
```

[image]

Comment: From System Settings -> Environment variables you have to set those two (seems doesn't exists there). So, just add paths of Android Home and Android Sdk. Google it how to set Environment variables.

Comment: I have set the Environment variables already. I have updated the images.

Comment: Inside of  "android" folder under your project, there is a file in it that is called local.properties, check on this file if the path sdk.dir=..........  is the same of what you have setted in Enviroment variables.

Comment: I checked it and It's the same