# Android Studio can launch AVD Emulator but IntelliJ 2023 can not

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have created an android emulator in Android Studio (2021.1.1 Patch 2) and can launch it there. In IntelliJ (2023.3 Ultimate Edition) it shows up in the Device Manager, but has a warning that "Missing system image for Google APIs [...]".

Earlier, I was able to launch the emulators also from IntelliJ, but was unable to create new ones. While debugging that, I discovered [this list of environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976475/2550406) and figured out that I had set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` years ago and removing it made IntelliJ use a different AVD folder.

Sidenote: IntelliJ will not register environment variable changes on a `File -> Invalidate -> Restart`; only on a full closing and manual re-opening.

Now I can see the device in IntelliJ but I can only launch it from Android Studio. The avd files seem to be located in `C:\Users\MYNAME\.android\avd`.
**How can I fix IntelliJ's Device Manager** so that I am able to launch the emulator from there, and ideally so that the debugger would also work with it? Currently I have to launch the app through the cmd or the IntelliJ command-line.

Clicking the Plus Button in IntelliJ Device Manager to create a new emulator device does not do anything.

The file `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.3\log\idea.log` contains the following, but it does not get logged reliably on button-press so maybe it is unrelated although it mentions AVD:

```
2023-12-09 13:28:25,672 [50214691] SEVERE - com.android.tools.idea.concurrency.CoroutinesUtils.kt - No value present
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:377)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.getDefaultDefinition(DeviceDefinitionList.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.setDefaultDevices(DeviceDefinitionList.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.<init>(DeviceDefinitionList.java:118)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.<init>(DeviceDefinitionList.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionPanel.$$$setupUI$$$(ChooseDeviceDefinitionPanel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionPanel.<init>(ChooseDeviceDefinitionPanel.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.createUIComponents(ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.$$$setupUI$$$(ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.<init>(ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdWizardUtils.createAvdWizard(AvdWizardUtils.java:270)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerImpl$createAvd$2.invokeSuspend(LocalEmulatorProvisionerFactory.kt:77)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:843)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$4.run(ApplicationImpl.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithEnabledImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:44)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:695)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$12(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithoutImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:355)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:793)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:354)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1014)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1014)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:848)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
2023-12-09 13:28:25,673 [50214692] SEVERE - com.android.tools.idea.concurrency.CoroutinesUtils.kt - IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3  Build #IU-233.11799.241
2023-12-09 13:28:25,673 [50214692] SEVERE - com.android.tools.idea.concurrency.CoroutinesUtils.kt - JDK: 17.0.9; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-12-09 13:28:25,673 [50214692] SEVERE - com.android.tools.idea.concurrency.CoroutinesUtils.kt - OS: Windows 10
2023-12-09 13:28:25,674 [50214693] SEVERE - com.android.tools.idea.concurrency.CoroutinesUtils.kt - Plugin to blame: Android version: 233.11799.264
2023-12-09 13:28:43,077 [50232096]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
```

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Does it help if you delete `C:\Users\<user name>\.android\avd` directory?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'll try this once I can, but I assume the answer is no. Because Android Studio is using that folder correctly, so I don't see how it could be the folder that is to blame. Unless of course AS and IntelliJ expect different formats of that same directory?

Comment: Having the same error in Android Studio Hedgehog

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Any solutions?

Comment: @Praxder I haven't had time to follow up on CrazyCoder's suggestion but if you do, you could tag them again. Maybe they know more.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with the same exception logged (but I am only using IntelliJ Ultimate, no Android studio or such). Deleting the avd directory does not help. @CrazyCoder

Comment: Please report a bug per https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html.