# install flutters alltough cmdline-tools is installed it does not work

Tags: flutter

In sdktools although Android SDK Command line is installed flutter doctor does not recognizes
I have Android installed in F directory and android sdk location in a directory F:\sdklocation

[image: sdktools capture]

I tried all the recommendations published and It is does not work

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.3155], locale es-ES)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

I installed and reintalled cmdline-tools I added new path F:/sdklocation and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible reasons for this issue, here are some of them.

1. The path of your SDK - (It should not contain any special characters).
2. Please check you environment variables, you might have missed to set the environment variables, here are the links for it -

**https://developer.android.com/tools/variables**

**[How do I set ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042638/how-do-i-set-android-sdk-home-environment-variable)**

Comment: I've tried all things and the problem continue:

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not permit that you install sdk outside the path C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk therefore it not posible to install sdk for instance f:sdklocation if you want to use flutter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).