# Visual Studio displays no_device_attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, android-emulator, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have purchase for enterprise edition of Xamarin products. Installed it. No i can create Android application, but can not test it because, No Devices Attached showing. What happening guys? I simply want to test it on Andorid Emulator

**EDITED:** 
when clicking on **Open Android Emulator Manager** and **Start Android SDK Manager** it does not do anythink. no any dialog or windows opening

**EDITED:** 
I see below error. could not create avd. but why it attempt it to create it on 'U:' disc. when 'U' disc is a network disk. which i connected to.

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.928] [Error] Could not create AVD 'MonoForAndroid API 15'. Failed to create AVD directory 'U:.android\avd\MonoForAndroid API 15.avd'

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] Creation of AVD 'MonoForAndroid API 15' failed with exception,

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'U:.android\avd\MonoForAndroid API 15.avd'.

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)

[2014-05-22 06:40:44.930] [Exception] at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.CreateAvd(String basePath, AvdInfo info, List`1 avdList)

[image: what sheet happining]

On command line

1.i am going to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools .

2.AND write emulator.exe -avd MonoForAndorid_API_ -partition-size 512 on command line.
It activate avd.

3.On visual Studio click on Start Android Adb command prompt.

4.After all a see MonoForAndorid_API_ attached to list.

But it is not to work with command line every time. i still looking for good answer

Comment: What does the Android SDK tool say? Before now I've had to mess around with drivers to make sure Windows knows about the right one for my phone.

Comment: @Jon Skeet , i can not start Android SDK to see what it says

Comment: Well why not? Not being able to start the SDK tools sounds like the first problem to fix. For example, the third icon to the right of where you can see "No devices attached" should start the Android SDK manager. There's also the Android Emulator Manager just to the left of that. If neither of those work, that's a significant installation issue.

Comment: i have 4 time reinstalled xamarin and sdk tools. But as you said icon  for statring Android Emulator Manager not opening emulator manager window

Comment: With no errors, no output in the console view etc? What happens if you try to launch it from Windows outside Visual Studio? It sounds like it may be best to talk to Xamarin support, to be honest...

Comment: i navigate to C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk. there is AVD Manager.exe And SDK Manager.exe contains. But when clicking on it, it closing automatically

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work-android - but again, this sounds like you should probably talk to Xamarin support.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Android SDK from the Xamarin Installer worked always very fine for me. Did you have any error messages while installing? 
Try to uninstall or repair the installation.
It would be good if you describe you environment (Os, admin rights, firewall etc.)

if you have a samsung smartphone, install Samsung Kies (Not version 3)
Then the samsung drivers get installed (you can deinstalled Kies after it works)
Also you have to enable developer options on the smartphone.

**UPDATE:**
So it seems your environment variable `USERPROFILE` is set to `U:` (which is very unusual)
It should be at least `U:\` to be a valid directory name.

"Normally" it points to `<ROOTDRIVE>:\Users\<username>` e.g. `C:\Users\testuser`.
My "AVDs" are stored under `C:\Users\testuser\.android\avd\`

I assume you or an administrator changed the environment variable `USERPROFILE` manually.
Maybe someone wanted to change the environment variable `HOMEDRIVE` which usually holds a drive name,
( e.g. `HOMEDRIVE=U:` ) and picked the wrong one `USERPROFILE`.

Comment: i have uninstalled and installed Xamarin from beginning. Now i am adding some part of this log file.

Comment: i what i saw. it attempts to create AVD's in 'U:' disk  which is a disk on network. and i have connected it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i first wanted to test my app on a real device. The phone turned up, but not in Xamarin.

It turned out to be a problem with my drivers (Windows). You need a special set of drivers, in my case from Samsung, for Xamarin to be able to recognize the phone. Not every system have them installed.

You also need to set up the device itself, so you can get the deugging and all that. You do that under "Developer options".

This guide should take you through most of it: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

Comment: I do not want to test it on any device yet. i want only to run in it on emulators