# Unable to open Android SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have downloaded the latest ADT Bundle 64 bit from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download.

I have 64 bit JDK 1.7 version and I have set the System variable in the Path
path - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60

I have unzip the zip file. I have tried to run the SDKManager.exe but nothing happened. 
The I tried to open

E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\tools\android.bat in the command prompt. 
and I have got the following error.

```
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\tools>android.bat
'"E:\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

I have a 64 bit JDK 1.6 which I am unable to uninstall from control panel for some reason. But this path is not there in Environmental Variables. From My eclipse I am able to run Java Programs which means by JDK is working. But know why this error is coming ?

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236420/893574

Comment: I did the same and I got the above error

Comment: I too have the same problem

Comment: Try to reinstall again

Comment: Related (and possible solution in): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367823/vs-android-not-suitable-java-found