# Uiautomatorviewer not finding JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, uiautomatorviewer

When I try to start uiautomatorviewer.bat i get this error:

> ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
>   Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
>   We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
>     http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
>
> If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
>   JDK folder.
>
> You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
>     http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

I have a working JDK at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9

My system variables are:

**JAVA_HOME** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9

**PATH** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;D:\Prac\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\bin;D:\Prac\AndroidSDK\tools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\25.0.3;D:\Prac\nodejs\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

( **ANDROID_HOME** D:\Prac\AndroidSDK )

My java version:

java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

echo %JAVA_HOME% is working OK (printing correct path).

I tried setting JAVA_HOME variable in the .bat script. That didn't work. (But that might be because I'm not sure where exactly in the script should I include it...)

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try reading https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it´s my english, but how is this document helpful to my situation? I have the JAVA_HOME variable set. Can you explain please?

Comment: The error "ERROR: No suitable Java found " means you have not set it properly. Check your version, see if you have multiple java home's . See if JRE HOME, Java Home etc are set properly.

Comment: Path was OK. Problem was the 64bit version of JDK. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367823/vs-android-not-suitable-java-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! The problem was that I was using 64bit JDK.

After installation of 32bit version all I needed to do was to set ANDROID_SWT system variable and it is working now.