# Appium tests executes with java 11 while uiautomatorviewer throws an error. Is uiautomatorviewer supported by java 11?

Tags: java, android, appium, android-uiautomator

Error while executing UIAUTOMATORVIEWER with Java11 installed and env path set right. I'm able to execute the appium tests with java11 though.

```
ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

Edit:
uiautomatorviewer works with java8, any workaround for java11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with UIAutomatorViewer, but since it is an old tool it can rely on 32-bit JDK. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33761319/4103101) for a fix.

If you are using Appium, **UIAutomatorViewer** is obviously a bad choice since Appium no longer use original UIAutomator under the hood: it was deprecated in favour of UiAutomator2 and Espresso drivers

You better try [official Appium desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases) instead