# Can't Open Android SDK Manager (tried various fixes)

Tags: java, android, windows, batch-file, cmd

So, no matter what I do and no matter what fix I try, I *still* can't open the Android SDK manager. I've gotten it working before, but I forget what I did. And my computer has had a fresh install since then, and is no longer running Windows 8 (it's now Windows 8.1). When I try to open SDK Manager.exe cmd flashes on the screen then disappears. Same with android.bat.

One person noted that it's important to read the Android bat file error because there are numerous reasons as to why it won't open, so I ran it and quickly pressed print screen to get the text in cmd that flashes on the screen and then disappears. I uninstalled, and reinstalled the Android Studio bundle so I could start over. This is the error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'Sarah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My user profile is not "Sarah" but actually "Eric & Sarah". Not sure if that has to do with anything. And I don't know how to change it. I have looked at the bat file and have told it before where my java.exe file is, but it makes no difference. My java.exe file is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe
```

The android.bat error is from a fresh install and I've made no changes whatsoever.

Comment: THat has everything to do with it.  It looks like the file has a bug where it isn't correctly handling spaces in filenames.  Quickest work around would be to use a directory without one.  Otherwise you can edit android.bat to correctly quote all filenames on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The *filename* path probably is not set correctly because of the spaces and amp used?.Not entirely sure.
Also, make sure you have set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the specified JDK path.

If nothing worked, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14269158/4422074) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236420/4422074). Seemed to worked for most people.
Hope i helped.