# I can't run SDK Manager - Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I need to run `SDK Manager` but get me bellow error :

[image]

And when I run the project get me this error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Android Studio, `select File -> Project Structure -> JDK location`.

Specify the `JAVA SDK folder`. **And also Make sure the folder does exist**.

This error cause there's not any folder or `SDK manager` found in this directory.you just need to do like above and Specify the `PATH` of `SDK Manager`.

**you can find the `PATH` of `sdk manager` in `SDK manager` or when you need to install it: e.x:**

[image]

Comment: if you are using windows, do this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14269158/4960200 - remember, this is another question! and open it with `RUN AS Administrator`

Comment: In this path select File -> Project Structure -> JDK location my Android location is C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and it is true but don't run .

Comment: Because this is in c drive and it should open with run as administrator.please follow this question in another thread.remember to do like above link in envoirnment variables and ...

Comment: I run with administrator but don't open  :(