# Android SDK won't start

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

I have installed java jdk 1.8 and later the android SDK. 
Android SDK manager won't open, it flashes for a second and nothing else happen. 
By running android.bat i get the following error:

```
C:\android\tools>android.bat

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no     swt-win32-3550 or
        swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

I have set the environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102.
```

Installed, reinstalled, redownloaded both java and android sdk, run as administrator, disabled antivirus, also tried many solutions found here without luck.

Comment: There is this similar thread which could help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234403/sdk-manager-exe-doesnt-work

Comment: OS type and version, memory (RAM), Eclipse version, where you downloaded it from... all good things to know...

Comment: Win7 ultimate 64bit, 8gb, not using Eclipse. Downloaded from official websites. thanks.

Comment: the second line of your debug says: org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary

Comment: what are you trying to do, the current jdk is 8 ?

Comment: don't have ecplipse intalled, I use b4a maybe this install some eclipse component. yes jdk 8

Comment: I repeat again, what are you trying to do ? without android eclipse or studio ?

Comment: I use a RAD called basic4android, and it requires JAVA and ANDROID SDK. I have been using this from years, now this problem happen with my new laptop. The software have always worked perfectly on win7.

Comment: By the way it is very naughty to use the JDK with android, but it does work if you know what you are doing (I do it) but then I am a very naughty boy ;O)

Comment: i.c. I think you need to get the WHOLE thing (then delete stuff you don't need) meaning a full eclipse or studio download WITH SDK integrated. And NDK for the full experience.

Comment: I think i need only the android SDK manager to works to continue my work. Not eclipse, thaks for your recommandations.

Comment: but what you are downloading HAS Eclipse dependencies... that's why I asked where you are downloading it from, you see ?

Comment: https://www.b4x.com/

Comment: You said you were using official sites, https://developer.android.com/index.html has android in the tilte, quite a big clue.

Comment: I dowloaded android sdk from developer.android and java from oracle ofc :')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117960/discussion-between-im7xs-and-jon-goodwin).

Comment: SNAFU Getting to the root of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing Android Studio, which should guide you through the setup and usually results with a working Android sdk. If the studio itself isn't desired, remove it but not the sdk when you are done.

Comment: what on earth is an adk ?

Comment: Android Developement Kit

Comment: It appears that my use of adk may not be quite right, the technical definition appears to be the Accessory Developement Kit, so adk may be ambiguous.

Comment: Not the best way but i resolved the problem by installing Studio. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following environment variables

**ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** - where you installed your sdk

Update your **PATH** variable to include this:

`;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%/bin`

Comment: How do i Update my PATH variable?

Comment: same place where you set environment variable `JAVA_HOME` (assuming you're on windows here)

Comment: I have added ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to be C:\android, but it looks you are talking of two different things. I am new of this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, too, that Java 8 isn't fully supported. In fact, no version of android prior to N (which is just a preview) supports Java 8 at all. Even Android N doesn't support every single language feature. See details on how to use Java 8 in Android and which of its features will be supported in N here:
https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

It's not possible to target Android N for a "real" app yet since there are no physical devices to run it, so I suggest sticking with JDK 1.7 for now.

Comment: The same happen with java SE 7. beside if java 8 is supported or not the problem is that the sdk manages won't start.

Comment: Either way, I don't recommend continuing to try to get it running with JDK 1.8, that'll just cause you further problems.